# Passing/Setting variables on ExpressibleByXXXXLiteral types does not work

Tags: swift

Here I have an example of an object conforming to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`

```swift
struct Foo: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    var raw: String

    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.raw = value
    }
}
```

Now using this can be as easy as these

```swift
func bar(foo: Foo) {}

let foo1: Foo = "example"
let foo2 = "example" as Foo

bar(foo: "example")
bar(foo: foo1)
bar(foo: foo2)
```

But doing the following won't work

```swift
let string: String = "example"

bar(foo: string) // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Foo'
let foo: Foo = string // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'Foo'
bar(foo: string as Foo) // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to type 'Foo' in coercion

// Even string interpolation doesn't work which is weird because it's a string
bar(foo: "\(string)" // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Foo'
```

Doesn't `String` also conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`? I have tried this with the other `ExpressibleBy` types and this seems to be the behaviour everywhere.

Is there a workaround I can use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExpressibleByStringLiteral` means to give you a shorthand to invoke `init(stringLiteral value: String)` by a string literal expression. Since `string` is not a literal, it cannot trigger this shorthand. You have to call the initialiser explicitly.

```
let string : String = "example"
bar(foo: Foo(stringLiteral: string))
```